# Is there a name for the place where a street name changes on the other side of an intersection?

Tags: phrase-requests

I think this is a common enough scenario in the US.

Imagine an intersection of a North/South road and an East/West road.

On the East side of the N/S road the E/W road is named something like 13th St. On the West side of the N/S road the E/W road is named something like University Ave.

Perhaps more common is the simple change of something like East Main St. to West Main St., but I'm not sure that's considered the same, or if there's a different term for that.

Does a term or phrase exist to describe this type of intersection that seems to define the cut-off points for different legal names for a continuous stretch of road?

---

Here's an [excerpt from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Street_or_road_name#Multiple_names_for_a_single_street) on street names, which talks about this:

> Where a street crosses or forms (straddles) a boundary, its two sides sometimes have different names. Examples include Seton Avenue (Bronx) / Mundy Lane (Mount Vernon, New York); Station Road (Portslade) / Boundary Road (Hove, East Sussex); Lackman Road (Lenexa) / Black Bob Road (Olathe, Kansas); Nieuwstraat (Kerkrade, Netherlands) / Neustraße (Herzogenrath, Germany), both names meaning 'New Street'.

But it also lacks a term or concise phrase for this convention.

Comment: For what it’s worth, GPS navigation systems usually describe this like “In 500 feet, 13th Street becomes University Avenue”.

Comment: @JonPurdy Yeah, but I wonder if there's some more obscure term, possibly civil engineering jargon, for it.

Comment: I just call it "obnoxious."

Comment: @altaltpow I have a feeling it generally happens when two previously separate roads are made to connect, such as when different townships or neighborhoods finally "connect" as a place expands. Although the "N. Main" "S. Main" stuff is pretty standard to start from.

Comment: Most highways in my area have two names. You drive from Asheville to Hendersonville on Hendersonville highway. You drive from Hendersonville to Asheville on Asheville highway. It's the same road, with the southbound and northbound lanes having different names. This is actually handy if there is a wreck - the name tells you which lanes are involved.

Answer (score 3):

I think that ***[junction](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/junction)***  can be used to refer to to the point where two roads  meet:

> - A place where two things join or meet, *especially a place where two roads or railway routes come together and one terminates*.

(AHD)

Comment: I think AHDEL express this poorly for once. I'm pretty sure they envisage a three-node at least for the road / railway layouts. Thus for these, 'junction' describes the topology rather than the naming protocol. The roads OP suggests have many junctions.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I like the choice of word but I think the best definition as used here is: the state of being joined. For example: "Intersection or not, this junction is where John St becomes Smith St."

Comment: @CandiedOrange Not even your example is picked up on a Google search. Choosing a definition that might seem to fit is unwise if few people use it that way in the context specified. Look at [the Wikipedia definition for 'road junction'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_(road)): A road junction is a location where multiple roads intersect, allowing vehicular traffic to change from one road to another. [Collins](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/junction) wisely narrows to '1. a place where **several** routes, lines, or roads meet, link, or cross each other: '

Comment: While this another term for intersections, general usage of junction isn't to refer to where one road becomes another, or the act of one road becoming another.

Answer (score 3):

I'm a highways engineer and we would call this a **transition**.

i.e. Broom Road *transitions* into Wickersley Road.

Comment: It would really help if you could post an example of this usage in a publication or textbook.